# Why is my FileSystemWatcher flag not updating in my razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this MVC 5 project set up to run with IIS Express on VS2015. It makes use of the FileSystemWatcher to monitor a folder and populate a list accordingly. Every 5 seconds I check the state of the FolderChanged flag. When it is true I want to alert the user and reset the flag to false. I have verified that the FileSystemWatcher works and the folder is being correctly monitored. But the problem is that the FolderChanged  flag is never seen to be true in the razor view but it does get updated in the Do_Something method. I fear that I may be missing something fundamentally simple but i have no idea what. Any help will be appreciated.

model class:

```
public class LogFileParser
{
    public List<string> FolderRecords { get; set; }
    public bool FolderChanged { get; set; }
    private FileSystemWatcher Folder_Watcher;
    public LogFileParser()
    {
        //set up list folder path and filesystemwatcher
        Folder_Watcher.Changed += Do_Something();
        Folder_Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void Do_Something(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //populate FolderRecords list
        FolderChanged = true;
    }
}
```

controller class:

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        LogFileParser log_file_parser = new LogFileParser();
        return View(log_file_parser);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(LogFileParser log_file_parser)
    {
        return View(log_file_parser);
    }
}
```

razor view:

```
@model MonitoringMachineParams.Models.LogFileParser
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Test</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            window.setInterval(function () { Update(); }, 5000);
        });
    function Update() {
        @if (Model.FolderChanged){
            Model.FolderChanged = false;
            Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FolderChanged);
            <text>alert("hello");</text>
        }}
</script>
```

Comment: Your mixing the server side and client side code up. Razor expressions run server side (before the page is sent to the client) your setInterval, etc is ran client side (on the browser). You can't call Razor code from Javascript. So Update() is an empty method. Inspect your markup and you'll see what I mean. You'll need to call the server (using ajax) to get the status of the file system watcher

Comment: Your script is only checking the original value of the model (when you passed it to the view). You need to use ajax to call a server method that checks the value and returns it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I'll take a look at using AJAX to call the server method.

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't understand how the web works. Once you render a view and send it to the client, it disconnects from the server. Unless you make AJAX requests to the server, or otherwise retrieve new data from the server, that folder can change all day long, but the client will not be aware of it.

Your entire design should change. You should have an Action which can return a value indicating if the folder changed, and client code to retrieve that data and act on it.